# Bjt for trigger MOSFET

Tags: microcontroller, bjt, power-electronics, mosfet-driver, basic

I my project MOSFET need 13 v 65% PWM to trigger but controller output is 5 volt then how can I amplify this in voltage

Comment: Is your positive rail also 5V? Can you use a 12 V rail? And will 12 V work for the MOSFET or must it really be 13 V? (Please add these details to the question.)

Answer (score 0):

Look for a MOSFET gate driver IC for a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with a  low-side MOSFET gate driver. Microchip, for example, has a wide range. You can do a parametric search. Here is a typical one - the [MIC4120/4129](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic4120.pdf) (originally Micrel):

[image]

Vs for this part can be as high as 20V so your 13V is okay. The input MOSFET and the 0.1mA current source produce a full swing voltage at the buffer input-- the 0.4mA current source is part of a speed-up circuit that draws relatively little current in the DC state (the 0.4mA current source switches off once the inverter output has risen close to the Vs supply voltage).

The output transistors can supply peak current in the 6A range which is desirable for charging and discharging your power MOSFET gate charge as quickly as possible. The net result is a simple-to-use circuit that can handle the gate charge in tens of ns. Because the relatively high and relatively fast-switching gate current flows in and out of the power supply pins on the gate driver, be sure to pay attention to the layout and provided adequate supply bypassing in accordance with the datasheet recommendations.

If you want a slower switching action (for example, to reduce EMI) at the expense of switching losses in your MOSFET you can add a gate resistor.